# How to build iOS App Store release file from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, release, xcodebuild

I can build an ad hoc release from command line but I struggle with building an App Store release from command line. How do you do that?

Ideally, I'd like to take an ad hoc release and transform that into an App Store release (resigning it?). That way I can test the ad hoc release and know the App Store release is identical.

If you can, please provide code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Ad-Hoc and AppStore builds have differences in provisioning profile only which is included within the app. The cert is the same. So you don't need to build Ad-hoc, then resign. Just build AppStore and you will able to install this build on device which have Ad-Hoc provisioning profile installed. That's what we always do.